# How to determine the frequency from Wavelet coefficeints

Tags: time-series

I created a Time series signal of 1024 values based on combination of sine waves

`Y=Sin(2pi*50*t) +Sin(2pi*300*t)` with `t` incremented in milliseconds (i.e) `f=1000Hz.`

I used R Discrete Wavelet package to get the Wavelet Coefficient using Daubechies transform with number of levels=4 . The output were the coefficients W1,W2,W3,W4 and an approximation V4

How to determine the frequency of input signal (50 and 300) from these coefficients ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you are using the wrong tool for this. You should use discrete Fourier transform, that will identify the frequencies. FOr instance, see the discussion [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/267652).